# How to pass Django textfield to html attribute and read with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, django

I want to pass a caption text for an image from a django template to javascript.
This is the relevant part of the html code:

```
<ul id="portfolio">
  {% for picture in gallery_selected.photo_set.all %}
    <li><img src={{ picture.path }} alt={{ picture.caption }}></li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Now I want to read the 'alt' tag from the images in javascript in order to create a fancy caption:

```
$("#portfolio img").click(function() {
var src = $(this).attr("src");
window.alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    alert(window.alt);
    });
```

I did not create the caption yet, I just wanted to test if the caption text is passed on (using the alert function).
However the alert only displays the first word of my caption text. As soon as a space occurs in the string, everything else is ignored.

Does anybody know how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap it in quotes. You should do that anyway with HTML attributes, for safety.

```
<img src="{{ picture.path }}" alt="{{ picture.caption }}">
```